# R: Crossvalidation of a lasso parameter and comparison to cv.glmnet

Tags: r, machine-learning, compare

I've two questions regarding the Cross-Validation. I tried to create a code for Cross-Validation by myself to improve my intuition. In particular I find the optimal penalize parameter lambda for the Lasso.

Here is my Code for the CV:

```
CV_lambda <- matrix(0, length(lambda_grid), 2)
colnames(CV_lambda) <- c("lambda", "CV-est")

#Loop for a vector of Lambda values
for(l in 1:length(lambda_grid)){
  #Number of folds
  nfolds <- 5
  #Fold IDs
  foldid <- sample(rep(seq(nfolds), length = N))

  #Output Store
  cv_out <- as.list(seq(nfolds))
  mspe_out <- matrix(0, 1, nfolds)

  #Cross-Validation
  for(i in seq(nfolds)){
    y_train <- y[!foldid == i,]
    X_train <- X[!foldid == i,]
    #Lasso is a self-written function, estimating a lasso-regression
    cv_out[i] <- lasso(y_train, X_train, lambda=lambda_grid[l])
    predict <- X[foldid == i,] %*% cv_out[[i]]
    mspe_out[i] <- mean((y[foldid == i,] - predict)^2)
  }
  CV_lambda[l,] <- c(lambda_grid[l],mean(mspe_out))
}
lambda_opt <- CV_lambda[which.min(CV_lambda[,2]),1]
```

I've two questions regarding the CV. I am sitting here for more than hours to find a solution to both questions. I would be very grateful, if some of you can help me. The Code is not very well and sparse, since I am a beginner. However, my questions are the following:

For the general understanding. LASSO-Regression requires a penalize parameter, which has a strong influence on the results. The goal is to choose this lambda, that reduces the mean squared prediction error.

1) Should the split into the sample be equal in every lambda-sequence or should it differ (as in my code). Im a bit skeptical about this.

2) Since I am very uncertain about my code, I want to compare my results to the glmnet. Is there a way to this ? The glmnet is also taking a random sample. A comparison isnt then possible. Has someone an idea how to "reproduce" the the cv.glmnet results with my code to find mistakes in my code ?

Comment: This sounds like your question is more about proper statistical analysis methods rather than specifically programming in R. Such questions are likely to get better answers on [stats.se]. Only post code there if it's directly relevant to your specific question (and I don't quite see how it is in this case, but maybe I'm missing something).

Comment: It is in this sense a programming question, that I need a way how I can compare two cross-validation (my self written one, with that one in a package)

Comment: Then define what “compare” means exactly. What specifically don’t you know how do to? Choosing a method to compare models usually falls in the realm of statistics. But if you exactly what you want to do (what method to use) and describe it here, then it could be a programming question.

Comment: I want to do a comparison for two reasons: 1) to figure out if my code is wrong or not, so both "methods" should give the same results and 2) if not I want a way to find the differences between both. So I have to find a way  to compare two functions that are running a Ccross-Validation, with the intention produce the same resutlts